# Update state of an slice from another slice

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using `redux-toolkit` and `rtk` query. I have scenario which I update my `auth` state when user login to the application and **I want to update the user information(authSlice) when user updates his information** but I am storing them in to 2 different slices `auth` and `user`. Is there any way to update `auth` state when user updates his information which takes place in `userSLice` ?

what is the best practice here? Should I combine 2 sates together if there is no way to update the state of another slice inside a different slice?

**userSlice**

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        dietPlan: null,
        workout: null,
        dailyDietPlan: null,
        dailyWorkout: null,
        information: null,
    } as InitialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addMatcher(
            userApi.endpoints.updateUserInfo.matchFulfilled,
            (state, {payload}) => {
                console.log(payload)
                this.dispatch(updateUser(payload.data)) // is there any way to do this ?
            }
        )
  }
})

export default userSlice.reducer
```

**authSlice**

```
const authSLice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: { user: null, token: null } as AuthState,
    reducers: {
        updateUser(state, action) {
            state.user = action.payload
        }
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addMatcher(
            authApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
            (state, {payload}) => {
                state.user = payload.data
            }
        )
        builder.addMatcher(
            authApi.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled,
            (state) => {
                state.user = null
            }
        )
    }
})

export default authSLice.reducer

export const { updateUser } = authSLice.actions
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the sate from another slice and this is intentional by design. So if any one wants to update another slice state after an rtk query fullfilled/rejected then they have to create an action which updates the data locally in redux and check to see if the `status === "fulfilled"` then dispatch that particular action.

**this is the reducer which will update the data locally**

```
type AuthState = {
    user: User | null
}

const authSLice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: { user: null } as AuthState,
    reducers: {
        updateUserLocally(state, action) {
            state.user.info = action.payload.info
        }
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addMatcher(
            authApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
            (state, {payload}) => {
                state.user = payload.data
            }
        )
        builder.addMatcher(
            authApi.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled,
            (state) => {
                state.user = null
            }
        )
    }
})

export default authSLice.reducer

export const { updateUserLocally } = authSLice.actions
```

**and inside my component**

```
    const user = useAppSelector(store => store.auth.user)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    
    const [updateUser, {status, data, error}] = useUpdateUserInfoMutation()
    
    const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
        updateUser(data)
    }
    
    if (status === 'fulfilled') {
        dispatch(updateUserLocally(data.data)) // this is the action
    }
```